Understanding the use of bitwise-operator in ternary-operator
I'm just learning how to code and while studying sorting algorithms I was asked to "see if you can combine the two lines in your if and else blocks into one line to make your code look a little cleaner."
const merge = (leftArray, rightArray) => {
  const sortedArray = [];
  while (leftArray.length > 0 && rightArray.length > 0) {
    if (leftArray[0] < rightArray[0]) {
      sortedArray.push(leftArray[0]);
      leftArray.shift();
    } else {
      sortedArray.push(rightArray[0]);
      rightArray.shift();
    }
  }

The first thing that came to my mind was to use ternary operator, and then, for some reason (never saw that being done before), I thought that I could just take the two actions for every condition, join them with '&&' and that would work.
But I had a typo!! I wrote '&' instead of '&&', and for my surprise, even with that it worked as intended. But I have no idea why, can't find anything that explains how this actually works and why. (Below is all the code and the part I re-wrote).
const mergeSort = (startArray) => {
  const length = startArray.length;
  if (length === 1) {
    return startArray;
  }
  
  const mid = Math.floor(length / 2);
  const leftArray = startArray.slice(0, mid);
  const rightArray = startArray.slice(mid, length);

  return merge(mergeSort(leftArray), mergeSort(rightArray))
}

const merge = (leftArray, rightArray) => {
  const sortedArray = [];
  while (leftArray.length > 0 & rightArray.length > 0) {
    leftArray[0] < rightArray[0] ? 
    sortedArray.push(leftArray[0]) & leftArray.shift() : 
    sortedArray.push(rightArray[0]) & rightArray.shift()
  }
  
  return sortedArray.concat(leftArray).concat(rightArray);
}

I would appreciate if some could shed some light to this.

That's the binary "and"; 1 & 1 = 1, 1 & 0 = 0. And then JS steps in and converts Boolean to Number (true = 1, false = 0) so it ends up working.

&& is a comparator. In this case, & and && will do the exact same (outside of possibly a few edge cases), but that's mostly because you're not using them as intended. Let me explain.
& is a bitwise operator. It takes two numbers and runs a Bitwise AND on each bit in each number to generate a result. The reason your code works is because you don't actually do anything with the output of your Bitwise AND. Instead, your goal is just to run two functions.
What you're telling JS to do here is to take the outputs of these two functions and AND them together. But, in order to get the outputs of the functions, JS has to execute them. So when it sees this block, it calls both functions, and then it also takes the Bitwise AND of the outputs (though you don't ever see this because you aren't doing anything with the outputs). In your case, this works fine because both functions end up getting called, and you get the expected output.

That makes perfect sense! This is very helpful. You feedback makes me wonder about the "correct" way to write that part then, should I use ',' instead of '&&'/'&', or is there another way to better to this?

To the best of my knowledge, you're totally right a comma operator is the "correct" way to do this, because it guarantees both statements will always execute. With &, I'm not entirely sure but I assume there's going to be some edge cases where the 2nd statement may not run, and you probably don't want to use && because the second statement only runs if the first statement evaluates to some form of true.

& Bitwise operator

The & operator is overloaded for two types of operands: number and
BigInt.

const a = 5; // 00000000000000000000000000000101
const b = 3; // 00000000000000000000000000000011

console.log(a & b); // 00000000000000000000000000000001

&& Logical AND operator

Returns true if both operands are truthy and false otherwise.

alert ( true && true ) ; // true 
alert ( false && true ) ; // false 
alert ( true && false ) ; // false 
alert ( false && false ) ; // false.

